# MySQL content pagination by rating

Tags: mysql, pagination

I have a simple mysql table with the following columns id, post, rating, created. I want to be able to paginate my posts by 10 according to their rating. The first solution is simple...

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE rating <= 1000
ORDER BY rating DESC, id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Problem is that if I have more than 10 posts with the same rating, they won't be selected. Is there a workaround?

Comment: this is a functional question your project manager or business analyst should answer.

Comment: I am a one man team, I don't know the answer

Comment: this is a business question. You could: 1/ include more results per page 2/ not care at all by the fact that some results are now showed 3/ include a date filter to only return first results...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE rating <= 1000
ORDER BY rating DESC, id DESC LIMIT x, 10
```

where x is an offset

x = 10 for 10-20

x = 20 for 20-30

etc

or just remove `LIMIT 10` to show all of them...

Comment: Offset is not good if you have a lot of data. I would like to avoid using it.

Comment: @Drug If you aren't willing to use the feature that is built in to handle situations like this, you should mention that in your question, along with an explanation of what 'not good' means to you.

Comment: i am puzzled as well, @WillemRenzema.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
*

FROM
posts

WHERE
rating <= 1000

ORDER BY
rating DESC, id DESC LIMIT start, howmany
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

SQL compliant:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT howmany OFFSET start
```

Comment: Offset is not good if you have a lot of data. I would like to avoid using it.